# Hibernate multiple group by month

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I want to join 2 `group by` queries. The mysql query looks like this:

```
SELECT d.m,d.fn/(d.fn+d2.tp)*100 FROM 
(
    SELECT MONTH(created_at) AS m, COUNT(*) AS fn 
    FROM documents 
    WHERE 
    document_state = "APPROVED" 
    GROUP BY m
) d 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT MONTH(created_at) AS m, COUNT(*) AS tp 
    FROM documents 
    WHERE 
    document_state = "AUTHENTIC" 
    GROUP BY m
) d2 
ON d.m = d2.m
```

I was unable to convert to HQL, because hibernate doesn't support subquery in the `from`.

Comment: Have you considered using a nativequery ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a native query, but this query can easily be re-formulated.

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(created_at), 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN document_state = "APPROVED" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
    / (
      COUNT(CASE WHEN document_state = "APPROVED" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
      + COUNT(CASE WHEN document_state = "AUTHENTIC" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
    ) * 100
FROM documents
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
```

so with HQL probably:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(d.createdAt), 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN d.state = "APPROVED" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
    / (
      COUNT(CASE WHEN d.state = "APPROVED" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
      + COUNT(CASE WHEN d.state = "AUTHENTIC" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
    ) * 100
FROM Document d
GROUP BY MONTH(d.createdAt)
```